# How can I see my iPad from my MacBook?

Tags: ipad

Is there an easy way to see my iPad screen from my MacBook?  I have Mocha VNC Lite and I can see my MacBook from my iPad, but I want to go the other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible *in a way*, but your question might need more detail if the answer is to be useful.

Because Mac OS X is a fully multitasking OS, you can VNC onto it and do all your normal stuff.  iOS though is very app centric, so to do this the other way would require you to run a VNC server type app on your iPad, but you would then be stuck in that app only without the possibility of subsequently running other apps, and not be able to actually use your iPad remotely at an OS level.

So, if you want to see it in order to be able to interact with it, using it normally from afar, the answer is no (although there may be jailbreak tweaks that allow this sort of thing to an extent - can't really comment on that tho).

If, however, I was to take your question literally, you just want to *see* the iPad screen on your iPad, then bingo, piece of cake if you have an iPad 2/3 - you can use Airplay mirroring to mirror the output of your iPad screen on your Mac using one of a variety of airplay receiving apps on OS X.  [See this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/50369/9495) for more details.