# How can I display my ipad screen on my PC?

Tags: applications, ipad

My company has several ipads standing in public places around town running our app. Sometimes the app crash and I have to go out to reboot it. Is there a way where I can sit in my office and log on to the ipads to check that the app is running?

Comment: Maybe you could create a logging system inside your app that tracks if the app is currently running or not

Answer (score 1):

if you had an iPad 2 or above, you could use Airplay Mirroring, and then setup an airplay server on your Mac which will allow you to receive a live video feed of the current display.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50373/9495), which is actually from a question about recording iPad screen output, which has most of the technical details.

It's not quite the same as "logging in" to your iPad, but the end result is the same.  The difficulty you will probably hit is in being on the same LAN which is a requirement of Airplay, but you could perhaps fix this with VPNs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you could use one of the well known MDM solutions and their free companion app to direct several iPads to run one app.

- [Casper Focus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/casper-focus/id635738553)
- http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-focus

I believe their free trial would let you get a cloud instance of the JSS set up and you could test on a few iPads to make sure the tool does what you need, but this is an amazing suite and might make financial sense based on how many calls you make and what your hourly rate is for managing the devices, wiping them, configuring them, tracking them, etc...