# How to record/stream iPhone 4 screen with iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, recording, video-capture

I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 7 and I want to record the screen from the device, or stream the screen of the device on my MacBook Pro and record it with QuickTime.

How can I do that?

<sup>I have AirServer, but it works only with iPhone 4s+! No jailbreak on my device.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the use of such software has a pre-requisite of *AirPlay Mirroring*, which is not supported by an iPhone 4 at any OS level, hence teh requirement for an iPhone 4s minimum.  If you had a device that supports it, then it's pretty straightforward (take a look at [this answer elswhere on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50369/how-to-do-a-screen-capture-from-ipad-3/50373#50373)) but with an iPhone 4, you are out of luck unless someone can suggest a way of enabling it with a Jailbreak hack.

Comment: Therefore for iPhone 4 without jailbreak there aren't possibilites to share screen to computers/mac? thanks for your reply

Answer (score -1):

You could try reflector, it emulates apple tv so you get your iphone screen on your mac.
search Reflector on google.

Comment: I already tried reflector. According to [compatible devices' page](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/compatible-devices/) iphone 4 is not supported. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For clarity, the compatibility issues do not stem from the software, but from the hardware, as such all similar software will have exactly the same issue.