# iPad: export Keynote project to video

Tags: ios, ipad, video, keynote, imovie

## Setup.

I'm running the most recent version of **Keynote** (as of April 3rd, 2014) on an iPad Air, WiFi-only version @ 16GBs.

## Task/issue.

I would like to export the project/slideshow to a video file (to then be able transfer the movie to my desktop PC running windows).

## Thoughts.

Is there any way to do this? I was thinking there must be a way to do it by using **iMovie** on iOS as a proxy somehow, but couldn't find any resources on the matter.

Comment: Is your desktop computer a Mac or a Windows PC?

Comment: It's a Windows PC (to my regret; can't afford a Mac yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keynote for iOS does not support this. Apparently Apple does not provide any mechanism for screen-recording (video) within iOS 7, and will not permit any third-party app that enables this. There have been some apps that can do screen recording on iOS 7, but they require jailbreaking the device, and are not authorized by Apple through the App Store.

The only way that I know to achieve this is by one of the following:

1) move your Keynote document that you created on iOS to Keynote on Mac OS X, which has a video export feature

2) If you have a Windows PC, you can use [Reflector for Windows](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/), which enables live video and audio recording of a "screen share" of what is playing on your iOS device. You establish a connection between your iOS device and your Windows computer, enable "Record" in Reflector, and then play back your Keynote document in full screen on your iOS device. You then have a video on your Windows computer that you can further edit.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use ScreenSharing on your iPad to a device that accepts AirPlay and then capturing the screen remotely.  I have answered a question on this scenario using a Mac with Quicktime and some other AirPlay software [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50373/9495), but I'm guessing you don't have a Mac.

Luckily you can use the software ([AirServer](http://www.airserver.com)) on a PC, so you can airplay mirror your entire screen to your PC, and then use a PC screen capture/recording program in place of Quicktime (You may have to ask another question elsewhere to get a decent recommendation, but a quick google throws up any number of possibilities e.g. [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/win-screen-recording-softwares/)).  Although, a quick peek suggests AirServer can now *record* all by itself on a Mac, with that feature coming to PC soon.  That takes a load of complexity out of the task :)  Other AirDisplay software is available, especially on Mac, but AirServer is merely the one I am most familiar with that I know does Windows too.

It's not perhaps the most elegant solution, but it's pretty nifty.

Answer (score 1):

Realizing you have a Windows PC without Keynote, and assuming this is a one-time thing you don't need to repeat regularly, I would be happy to convert it for you free of charge if you'd like.

Comment: Why not also explain how you convert things? That might scale faster than you fixing things, but the offer is quite kind so no harm there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Mac to do the conversion: From [Apple Support:](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2655?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

With Keynote you can export your presentation to a number of file formats. Follow these steps to create a file that you can use in iMovie:

1. Open your presentation in Keynote
2. Choose File > Export.
3. Select QuickTime as the file format.
4. Select "Fixed Timing" for playback.
5. Do not select the manual advance option; the resulting file may not import into iMovie.
6. Select "Full Quality Large" for the format setting.
7. Click Next.
8. Name and save your movie.

Follow these steps to import this file into iMovie:

1. Open iMovie
2. Choose File > Import Movies.
3. Locate your movie, saved in step 7 above.
4. Click Import.

Comment: the question is asking about doing this on the iPad, not on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion of using screen capture software. Here's a [comparison list](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/blog/10-best-screen-recording-software-for-windows-free-and-paid/) that may be helpful in your search.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain to link-only answers.  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Links can change over time and then we lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.  - From Review -

Answer (score -2):

It appears that one used to be able to export a Keynote Presentation to Imovie on the same Ipad. But sadly, it looks like Apple has has taken this opportunity away. Once saved in MP4 format, you should them be able to transfer it to your PC several ways.

Comment: Maybe trying expanding on what "several ways" are available to the person asking the question?